# ARCH nested in GARCH

Tags: time-series, garch

I have a quick question. I found this notion of "ARCH nested in GARCH" in one of the papers I'm reading right now, and I can't quite understand what it means.

if anyone can help, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The GARCH ($p$,$q$) model for a time series  $(x_{t})_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is defined as
\begin{align}
x_t &= \sigma_t \epsilon_t \\
\sigma_t^2 &= a_0 + a_1 x_{t-1}^2 + \dots + a_p x_{t-p}^2 + b_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2 + \dotsb + b_q \sigma_{t-q}^2.
\end{align}

ARCH nested in GARCH means that ARCH is a restricted version of GARCH, i.e. ARCH model is

\begin{align}
x_t &= \sigma_t \epsilon_t \\
\sigma_t^2 &= a'_0 + a'_1 x_{t-1}^2 + \dots + a'_p x_{t-p}^2,
\end{align}

with restriction $b_i = 0$ for $i\in[q]$.